# How can I re-arrange JSON with angular 2

Tags: json, typescript

I have JSON that looks like this

```
const err =    [
      {
        "Error": Name Not Valid",
        "Content": [
          {
            "Name": "Johnz"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "Error": "Data Not Valid",
        "Content": [
          {
            "Investor": "3785388",
            "ManagedBy": "Johnz"
          },
          {
            "Investor": "1111111",
            "ManagedBy": "Mary"
          }
        ]
      }]
```

How can I set it so it looks like this? I need to move anything that appears in the content array to the main structure where title is.

```
 const err=   [
      {
        "Error": "Name Not Valid",
        "Name": "Johnz"
      },
      {
        "Error": "Data Not Valid",
        "Investor": "3785388",
        "ManagedBy": "Johnz"
      },
      {
        "Error": "Data Not Valid"
        "Investor": "1111111",
        "ManagedBy": "Mary"
        }]
```

Comment: What you show there is not JSON, it seems to be JS code (or ECMA Script or typescript or whatever today's flavour is).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It helps if you define a minimal type for the **err** variable.

An option then would be:

```js
const err: { Error: string, Content: any[] }[] = [
    {
        "Error": "Name Not Valid",
        "Content": [
            {
                "Name": "Johnz"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Error": "Data Not Valid",
        "Content": [
            {
                "Investor": "3785388",
                "ManagedBy": "Johnz"
            },
            {
                "Investor": "1111111",
                "ManagedBy": "Mary"
            }
        ]
    }];

const flattenedError = err.map(error => {
    const flattened = { error: error.Error };

    return error.Content.reduce((acc, curent) => {
        Object.keys(curent).forEach((key) => {
            acc[key] = curent[key];
        });
        return acc;
    }, flattened);
});
```

A working example can be found [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=const%20err%3A%20%7B%20Error%3A%20string%2C%20Content%3A%20any%5B%5D%20%7D%5B%5D%20%3D%20%5B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Error%22%3A%20%22Name%20Not%20Valid%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Content%22%3A%20%5B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Name%22%3A%20%22Johnz%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Error%22%3A%20%22Data%20Not%20Valid%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Content%22%3A%20%5B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Investor%22%3A%20%223785388%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22ManagedBy%22%3A%20%22Johnz%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Investor%22%3A%20%221111111%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22ManagedBy%22%3A%20%22Mary%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20flattenedError%20%3D%20err.map(error%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20flattened%20%3D%20%7B%20error%3A%20error.Error%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20error.Content.reduce((acc%2C%20curent)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Object.keys(curent).forEach((key)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20acc%5Bkey%5D%20%3D%20curent%5Bkey%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20acc%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%20flattened)%3B%0D%0A%7D)%3B).

Comment: This works one more thing. Can I add default empty fields using that method? Lets say I want to add "Investor" and "ManagedBy" to the first array and also "Name" to the second array. How can I do that dynamically?

Comment: you can initialize the flattened object with them if you want. But unless you need them as an empty string a non defined property will behave mostly the same in most cases.